# Convert this For statement into a While statement?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I have to convert this For loop into a while loop, but instead of finding the busiest hour (highest integer) i need to find the quietest one (lowest integer). I'm stuck and cant figure it out.

```
public int busiestHour()
    {
        int busiest = hourCounts[0];
        for (int hour = 1; hour <= hourCounts.length - 1; hour++)
        {
            if (busiest < hourCounts[hour])
            {
                busiest = hourCounts[hour];
            }
        }
        return busiest;
    }
```

Comment: What did you try? Why did it fail? Where is the code for your attempt? What happened when you debugged? What else did you try to debug? Did you print any statements to help you understand the flow? Have you tried writing the flow down with a pen and paper?

Comment: why a `while`? one way or another you've got to scan the entire array, so a for would work pretty much exactly the same as a while.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, add the homework tag so we know not to question why you might want to do some potentially contrived thing.

Comment: Although it's called `busiest`, this loop actually returns the lowest integer, so it's what you need. As for converting a `for` into a `while`... Read a little about `for` loops. A `for` is just shorthand for a specific type of `while`.

Comment: @fd The `homework` tag is deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Oh sorry!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
public int quietesthour(int[] hourCounts) {
    int hour = 1;
    int quietest = hourCounts[0];

    while (hour < hourCounts.length) {
        if (hourCounts[hour] <= quietest) {
            quietest = hourCounts[hour];
        }
        hour++;
    }

    return quietest;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hint - these two loops are exactly equivalent. In fact the first is just a short-hand way of writing the second.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    int j = 0;
    while (j < 10) {
        System.out.println(j);
        j += 1;
    }
```